# When and how should use multiple spiders in one Scrapy project

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using `Scrapy`, it is great!  so fast to build a crawler.  with the number of web sites are increasing,  need to create new spiders, but these web sits are the same type,
all these spiders use  same items, pipelines, parsing process

the contents of the project directory:

```
test/
├── scrapy.cfg
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── items.py
    ├── mybasespider.py
    ├── pipelines.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── spider1_settings.py
    ├── spider2_settings.py
    └── spiders
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── spider1.py
        └── spider2.py
```

To reduce source code redundancy, `mybasespider.py` has a base spider `MyBaseSpider`, 95% source code are in it,  all other spiders inherited from it, if a spider has some special things, override some 
`class methods`, normally only need to add several lines source code to create a new spider

Place all common settings in `settings.py`,   one spider's special settings are in `[spider name]_settings.py`, such as:

the special settings of `spider1` in `spider1_settings.py`:

```
from settings import *

LOG_FILE = 'spider1.log'
LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'
JOBDIR = 'spider1-job'
START_URLS = [
    'http://test1.com/',
]
```

the special settings of `spider2` in `spider2_settings.py`:

```
from settings import *

LOG_FILE = 'spider2.log'
LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'
JOBDIR = 'spider2-job'
START_URLS = [
    'http://test2.com/',
]
```

`Scrapy` uses `LOG_FILE`, `LOG_LEVEL`, `JOBDIR` before launching a spider;

All urls in `START_URLS` are filled into `MyBaseSpider.start_urls`, different spider has different contents, but the name `START_URLS` used in the base spider `MyBaseSpider` isn't changed.

the contents of the `scrapy.cfg`:

```
[settings]
default = test.settings
spider1 = spider1.settings
spider2 = spider2.settings

[deploy]
url = http://localhost:6800/
project = test
```

To run a spider, such as `spider1`:

1. `export SCRAPY_PROJECT=spider1`
2. `scrapy crawl spider1`

But this way can't be used to run spiders in `scrapyd`. `scrapyd-deploy` command always uses `'default'` project name in `scrapy.cfg` 'settings' section to build an `egg file` and deploys it to `scrapyd`

Have several questions:

1. Is this the way to use multiple spiders in one project if I don't create a project per spider? Are there any better ways?
2. How to separate a spider's special settings as above which can run in `scrapyd` and reduce source code redundancy
3. If all spiders use a same `JOBDIR`, is it safe to run all spiders concurrently? Is the persistent spider state corrupted?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a great approach. Your strategy seems very manageable.

I'm not sure how to answer 2. As far as 3 goes it should be safe to run them concurrently unless there is some 3rd party resource that will cause a race condition.

Comment: I wrote a tutorial for this, we are using it in our projects. [Using multiple spiders in a Scrapy project](http://lnxpgn.github.io/2015/07/27/using-multiple-spiders-in-a-scrapy-project/)

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

As all spiders should have their own class, you could set the settings per spider with the `custom_settings` class argument, so something like:

```
Class MySpider1(Spider):
    name = "spider1"
    custom_settings = {'USER_AGENT': 'user_agent_for_spider1/version1'}

Class MySpider1(Spider):
    name = "spider1"
    custom_settings = {'USER_AGENT': 'user_agent_for_spider2/version2'}
```

this `custom_settings` will overwrite the ones on the `settings.py` file so you could still set some global ones.

Comment: thanks to whoever downvoted my answer without an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will answer to your first question but I use scrapy with multiple spiders and in the past i use the command

```
scrapy crawl spider1
```

but if I had more then one spider this command activate it or another modules so I start to use this command:

```
scrapy runspider <your full spider1 path with the spiderclass.py>
```

example: "scrapy runspider home/Documents/scrapyproject/scrapyproject/spiders/spider1.py"

I hope it will help :)

Answer (score 1):

Good job! I didn't find better way to manager multiple spiders in the documentation.

I don't know about scrapyd. But when run from command line, you should set environment variable `SCRAPY_PROJECT` to the target project.

see [scrapy/utils/project.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/utils/project.py#L60)

```
ENVVAR = 'SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE'

...

def get_project_settings():
    if ENVVAR not in os.environ:
        project = os.environ.get('SCRAPY_PROJECT', 'default')
        init_env(project)
```